# Tkinter labels overlapping

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm very very new to python and tkinter and I'm trying to make a really simple and basic calculator.

This code works as I intended except that if I want to print out 2 results without restarting the program the labels overlap.

This is what it looks like when I print 50 * 50 and then change it to 50 / 50 without restarting the program.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

w = Tk()

#****FUNCTIONS****

def multiply():

    number1 = float(e1.get())
    number2 = float(e2.get())

    result1 = number1 * number2
    resultlabel1 = Label(w, text=result1)
    resultlabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)

def division():

    number1 = float(e1.get())
    number2 = float(e2.get())
    result1 = number1 / number2
    resultlabel1 = Label(w, text=result1)
    resultlabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)

def addition():
    number1 = float(e1.get())
    number2 = float(e2.get())
    result1 = number1 + number2
    resultlabel1 = Label(w, text=result1)
    resultlabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)

def subtraction():
    number1 = float(e1.get())
    number2 = float(e2.get())
    result1 = number1 - number2
    resultlabel1 = Label(w, text=result1)
    resultlabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)





# ****LABELS, ENTRIES AND BUTTONS****

l1 = Label(w, text="First number: ")
l2 = Label(w, text="Second number: ")
e1 = Entry(w)
e2 = Entry(w)
b1 = Button(w, text="*", command=multiply)
b2 = Button(w, text="/", command=division)
b3 = Button(w, text="-", command=subtraction)
b4 = Button(w, text="+", command=addition)
b5 = Button(w, text="Exit", command=w.quit)



#****PLACEMENTS****

l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

b1.grid(row=0, column=2)
b2.grid(row=0, column=3)
b3.grid(row=1, column=3)
b4.grid(row=1, column=2)
b5.grid(row=2, column=4)

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

define your `resultlabel1` outside of your functions where the rest of the GUI is created. Then add

`resultlabel1.config(text=result1)`

to all your functions instead - even though the label is defined below them, it will work, as it is now a global variable. This will, instead of creating a new label everytime, just change the displayed text in one Label, thus preventing any overlap.

Answer (score 1):

In each of your functions, you create a new `resultLabel1`. This means you create new label every time you do a calculation, instead of overwriting or editing the same label.

Every time you create a new label in each function, you are creating a `local` variable. This means the variable can only be used within that function, which is why it isn't overwritten in all the other functions.

To solve this, you could create the `Label` widget with all of the others:

```
l1 = Label(w, text="First number: ")
l2 = Label(w, text="Second number: ")
e1 = Entry(w)
e2 = Entry(w)
b1 = Button(w, text="*", command=multiply)
b2 = Button(w, text="/", command=division)
b3 = Button(w, text="-", command=subtraction)
b4 = Button(w, text="+", command=addition)
b5 = Button(w, text="Exit", command=w.quit)
resultlabel1 = Label(w)  # leave the text empty when you first create it
```

Then you can add it to the window with all of the other widgets too:

```
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
l2.grid(row=1, column=0)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

b1.grid(row=0, column=2)
b2.grid(row=0, column=3)
b3.grid(row=1, column=3)
b4.grid(row=1, column=2)
b5.grid(row=2, column=4)

resultlabel1.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

--

By creating your label *outside* of a function, it means that it is a `global` variable, and can be used everywhere.

I'll use the multiply function as an example. The first thing you would need to do would be to globalise `resultLabel1`. This means that it can be used within the function as a `global` variable, and that the function shouldn't use its own `local` variable.

Now, instead of creating a new instance of `resultLabel1` every time you run a calculation, you should edit the existing label you already made. Using `global resultLabel1` lets us access the variable from within this function. To edit a widget, you use `.config(**options)`, and give the things you want to change as the arguements [(see here for more)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method). So in this case, you would run `resultLabel1.config(text=result1)`

```
def multiply():
    global resultLabel1  # means the function can use the global variable

    number1 = float(e1.get())
    number2 = float(e2.get())
    result1 = number1 * number2

    resultlabel1.config(text=result1)  # edits the variable's text
```

Comment: the line `global resultLabel1` is obsolete.